# Why does my jacaranda tree have no leaves falling off?

Tags: identification, trees

In my city, there are many jacaranda trees, but they bloom little, in The autumn, and their leaves do not fall in winter. Why?!!!

It does not bloom, perhaps because of the elements in the soil. I have read about that, but why do a few bloom in the autumn, and their leaves do not fall, they are evergreen!

It may not be a jacaranda, but its leaves, flowers, and seeds look exactly like a jacaranda. Is this another type?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you post a photograph or two?

Comment: I added 3 photos @Chenmunka